# differential equations: phase flows in 1 and 2 dimensions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was participating in a [conversation](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/fitting-neural-ode-to-periodic-time-series/42263/15) about fitting a one dimensional ODE to a periodic time series. The data in question was the [mauna loa dataset](https://scrippsco2.ucsd.edu/data/atmospheric_co2/primary_mlo_co2_record.html). One of the people on the thread was saying that this data could not be fit by a one-dimensional ODE. My background is statistics, so I have not looked at my Strogatz book in a while.

I just wanted to make sure that my logic was sound here. The reason that you cannot model this curve using a one dimensional ODE is that you cannot have oscillations in one dimension. I suppose you can't have the phase flow cross itself, and in one dimension that means the derivative cannot change from positive to negative--as would be necessary for an oscillation.

[image: Mauna Loa Dataset]

After looking at Strogatz again, it seems like one dimensional ODE seem to proceed towards an asymptote. But they key reason for this behavior is that in one dimension, the phase trajectory cannot reverse itself--so it has to either go to +/-infinity or stop at a fixed point. The figure below shows the time evolution for a one-dimensional ODE from chapter 2 of Strogatz.

[image]

Now I could model this dataset using a 2 dimensional ODE right, and that should not have any trouble with capturing the oscillation. If I remember in 2 dimensions we cannot have chaotic behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can  model this as the solution of a first-order ordinary differential equation!

Consider for example $\frac{dy}{dt} = a y(t)+ p(t)$ where $a$ is a constant and $p(t)$ is a periodic inhomogeneous forcing term.
Without $p(t)$ the solution is pure exponential growth.  The periodic forcing term $p(t)$ has the effect of imposing  an additional wave-like component to the full solution.
[image]

Comment: that is an interesting idea. Yeah, so the forcing term can introduce the period behavior, haha. But I get your point that without this forcing term, I would just get exponential growth.